# How to find a sequence of elements in an (only kinda) ordered list

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have a list of log entries, which looks somewhat like this:

```
a = [
    {‘log’: ‘abc’, ‘time’: 0},
    {‘log’: ‘123’, ‘time’: 1},
    {‘log’: ‘def’, ‘time’: 2},
    {‘log’: ‘abc’, ‘time’: 2},
    {‘log’: ‘ghi’, ‘time’: 3},
    {‘log’: ‘def’, ‘time’: 3}
]
```

Where time is accurate to the second, but events marked as happening at the same time, may have occurred at any order relative to each other. For example, in the above list, `a[5]` may have happened chronologically before `a[4]`.

Now say have a sequence of logs I want to match against `a`:

```
b = [
    {‘log’: ‘abc’, ‘time’: 0},
    {‘log’: ‘def’, ‘time’: 1},
    {‘log’: ‘ghi’, ‘time’: 2}
]
```

I would hope to find the ordered sebset of `a` with the log entries from `b`, where `subset[0]['time']` is as close as possible to `subset[-1]['time']` (in other words, where the duration of time spanned by the subset is as small as possible):

```
>>> f(a, b)
[{‘log’: ‘abc’, ‘time’: 2}, {‘log’: ‘ghi’, ‘time’: 3}, {‘log’: ‘def’, ‘time’: 3}]
```

EDIT for further clarification:

If the subsets of `a`, which match `b` are:

```
# a[0], a[4], a[5]
a1 = [
    {‘log’: ‘abc’, ‘time’: 0},
    {‘log’: ‘ghi’, ‘time’: 3},
    {‘log’: ‘def’, ‘time’: 3}
]

# a[3], a[4], a[5]
a2 = [
    {‘log’: ‘abc’, ‘time’: 2},
    {‘log’: ‘ghi’, ‘time’: 3},
    {‘log’: ‘def’, ‘time’: 3}
]
```

Then the entries in `a1` occurred over a period of 3 seconds, and the entries in `a2` occurred over a period of 1 second. As the duration of the entries in `a2` is shorter than that of `a1`, I would hope to be returned `a2`.

Comment: One of the "a[5]" is a typo?

Comment: Fixed, thanks. To whoever voted to close, would you mind giving feedback on how I can ask a better question instead?

Comment: Can you define explicitly `over the shortest period of time`? I'm not sure how you get your result.

Comment: It is a close vote for being unclear. Consider explaining more about the rules which  allow to derive the shown desired output from the two input arrays. Also what is a "kinda ordered list"? How is the desired output "finding elements" in one? What relevance has the possibility to reorder on the same second time stamp? What relevance has the time value in b? In short, even if you cannot code it, you need to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Well, I believe the problem is clear.. The one thing I missed is: do `logs` in `A` have to be consecutive? (e.g. could you have a log `xyz` between `ghi` and `def` in `A`?)

Comment: @RafaelC They do not need to be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly, this solution works for the example data provided.

the overall approach is:

1. find matches
2. look for duplicates
3. check if putting each duplicate back into the original matches reduces the time elapsed.
4. repeat this until there are no duplicates and the time elapsed has reduced from the original list of matches. or until there are no more duplicates.

Its a bit convoluted & likely inefficient for larger problems but hopefully the comments help you in the right direction.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


from collections import Counter
import copy


def drop_repeated_logs(list_of_dicts):
    """
    drop the repeated text in logs and compute a new time range
    if the new elapsed time range is lower, then return that list of dictionaries
    """
    only_logs = [d['log'] for d in list_of_dicts]
    original_range = list_of_dicts[-1]['time'] - list_of_dicts[0]['time']
    counts = Counter(only_logs)
    original_max_count = counts[max(counts,key=lambda i:counts[i])]
    original_len = len(list_of_dicts)

    print(counts)
    for log_txt in only_logs:
        num_occ = counts[log_txt]
        if num_occ > 1:
            # list of matching log subsets without repeats
            new_d = [entry for entry in list_of_dicts if entry['log']!=log_txt]
            print new_d
            # repeating log subset entries
            entries_to_try = [entry for entry in list_of_dicts if entry['log']==log_txt]
            print entries_to_try
            for repeat in entries_to_try:
                temp_d_list = copy.copy(new_d)
                # add one of the repeated entries to the matches
                temp_d_list.append(repeat)
                newly_sorted = sorted(temp_d_list, key=lambda k:k["time"])
                # check what the new "time elapsed"
                new_range = newly_sorted[-1]['time'] - newly_sorted[0]['time']
                print "Newly computed range of {}: {}\n".format(newly_sorted,new_range)
                new_len = len(newly_sorted)

                # we should return an updated list if the range is lower or we were able to get one repeated entry out
                # see if the new time elapsed is an improvement from the original
                if new_range < original_range :
                    print("Found a smaller range, returning: {}".format(new_range))
                    return (new_range,newly_sorted)
            if new_range == original_range and new_len < original_len:
                print("The range is unchanged, but got rid of a duplicate log text")
                return (new_range,newly_sorted)

    return original_range,list_of_dicts
```

## data example provided

```
b = [{"log": "abc", 'time': 0},
{'log': 'def', 'time': 1},
{'log': 'ghi', 'time': 2}
]

a = [
    {'log': 'abc', 'time': 0},
    {'log': '123', 'time': 1},
    {'log': 'def', 'time': 2},
    {'log': 'abc', 'time': 2},
    {'log': 'ghi', 'time': 3},
    {'log': 'def', 'time': 3}
]
```

## only get the log text from the data provided

```
a_logs = [d['log'] for d in a]
b_logs = [d['log'] for d in b]
```

## find the intersection of two lists

```
def intersection(a,b):
    return list(set(a)&set(b))
```

## the repeating logs between the a and b sets of data

```
logs_of_interest = intersection(a_logs,b_logs)
```

## find all the entry in a that match with an entry in b

```
matches_in_a = [entry for entry in a if entry['log'] in logs_of_interest]
```

## sort matched entries in order of time key

```
sorted_matches = sorted(matches_in_a, key=lambda k: k['time']) 
print(sorted_matches)
```

## find range of times (this is the parameter to minimize)

```
rnge = sorted_matches[-1]['time']-sorted_matches[0]['time']

sorted_logs = [d['log'] for d in sorted_matches]

log_counts = Counter(sorted_logs)
max_count = log_counts[max(log_counts,key=lambda i:log_counts[i])]
print "max count: {}".format(max_count)

# intitialize a lower range to get the while loop going
lower_range = rnge+1

while lower_range > rnge or max_count > 1:
    lower_range, sorted_matches = drop_repeated_logs(sorted_matches)
    sorted_logs = [d['log'] for d in sorted_matches]
    log_counts = Counter(sorted_logs)
    print("log counts: {}".format(log_counts))
    max_count = log_counts[max(log_counts,key=lambda i:log_counts[i])]
    print "MAX COUNT: {}".format(max_count)
    print "NEW LOWER RANGE: {}".format(lower_range)


print("FINAL ANSWER: range: {}; {}".format(lower_range,sorted_matches))
```

## output

```
> [{'log': 'abc', 'time': 2}, {'log': 'ghi', 'time': 3}, {'log': 'def', 'time': 3}]
```